# Can't delete a specific row from a specific table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

edit 1:  when I inspect element for the unfollow submit button and change the variable at the end of the url to one I know is a relationships row id it deletes the correct row but then tells me it cant find a user with that id to redirect me to.  so I think it is sending the users id to the destroy method which brings up an error if no row with that id exists or deletes the wrong relationship if one does exit.  It then uses that same variable to reroute you back to the users profile you were looking at.

edit2: The unfollow part has been resolved by adding (@relationship) to the form_tag in the view.  now the redirect in the relationship controller 'redirect_to user_path params[:id]' is looking for an index method in the userscontroller when I think I want it to look for the show method so I am trying to figure that part out now

I am following a rails tutorial and have run into a problem.  From the comments the tutorial code is wrong so I am wondering if someone here can point me towards the solution so I can continue with the rest of the tutorial

I have users who can create posts(ribbits).  a user can follow other users.  I am trying to get the unfollow feature to work.  There is a relationships table which has the fields id, follower_id, followed_id and timestamps.

The relationship create method works fine and all fields get populated correctly.  when I click unfollow I get the following error

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in RelationshipsController#destroy
>   Couldn't find Relationship with id=2

it points to the  line of this code from the relationships_controller::destroy method

```
        @relationship = Relationship.find(params[:id])
```

I am not sure were the params[:id] is coming from or why it is being used. from what I can tell the followed persons user id is being passed to the destroy method not the actual relationships id

here is the rest of the code

relationshipsController

```
class RelationshipsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @relationship = Relationship.new
        @relationship.followed_id = params[:followed_id]
        @relationship.follower_id = current_user.id

        if @relationship.save
            redirect_to User.find params[:followed_id]
        else
            flash[:error] = "Couldn't Follow"
            redirect_to root_url
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @relationship = Relationship.find(params[:id])
        @relationship.destroy
        redirect_to user_path params[:id]
    end
end
```

user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    before_save :create_avatar_url


    has_secure_password

    has_many :ribbits

    has_many :follower_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "followed_id"
    has_many :followed_relationships, class_name: "Relationship", foreign_key: "follower_id"

    has_many :followers, through: :follower_relationships
    has_many :followeds, through: :followed_relationships


    validates :name, presence: true

    validates :username, uniqueness: true, presence: true

    validates :email, uniqueness: true, presence: true, format: { with: /\A[\w.+-]+@([\w]+.)+\w+\z/ }

    before_validation :prep_email

    def create_avatar_url
        self.avatar_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/#{Digest::MD5.hexdigest(self.email)}?s=50"
    end

    def following? user
        self.followeds.include? user
    end

    def follow user
        Relationship.create follower_id: self.id, followed_id: user.id
    end

    private

    def prep_email
        self.email = self.email.strip.downcase if self.email
    end
end
```

user controller

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end

    def create
        @user = User.new(user_params)

        if @user.save
            session[:user_id] = @user.id
            redirect_to @user, notice: "Thank you for signing up for Ribbit!"
        else
            render 'new'
        end
    end

    def show
        @user = User.find(params[:id])
        @ribbit = Ribbit.new

        @relationship = Relationship.where(
            follower_id: current_user.id,
            followed_id: @user.id
            ).first_or_initialize if current_user
    end

    private

    def user_params
        params.require(:user)
                .permit(:avatar_url, :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :username)
    end
end
```

show.html.erb

```
<% if current_user %>
<div id="createRibbit" class="panel right">
    <h1>Create a Ribbit</h1>
    <p>
    <%= form_for @ribbit do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_area :content, class: 'ribbitText' %>
        <%= f.submit "Ribbit!" %>
    <% end %>
    </p>
</div>
<% end %>
<div id="ribbits" class="panel left">
    <h1>Your Ribbit Profile</h1>
    <div class="ribbitWrapper">
        <img class="avatar" src="<%= @user.avatar_url %>">
        <span class="name"><%= @user.name %></span> @<%= @user.username %>
        <p>
        <%= @user.ribbits.size %> Ribbits
        <span class="spacing"><%= @user.followers.count %> Followers</span>
        <span class="spacing"><%= @user.followeds.count %> Following</span>
        </p>
        <% if current_user and @user != current_user %>
            <% if current_user.following? @user %>
                <%= form_tag relationship_path, method: :delete do %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Unfollow" %>
                <% end %>
            <% else %>
                <%= form_for @relationship do %>
                    <%= hidden_field_tag :followed_id, @user.id %>
                    <%= submit_tag "Follow" %>
                <% end %>
            <% end %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="panel left">
    <h1>Your Ribbits</h1>
    <% @user.ribbits.each do |ribbit| %>
        <div class="ribbitWrapper">
            <img class="avatar" src="<%= @user.avatar_url %>">
            <span class="name"><%= @user.name %></span> 
            @<%= @user.username %> 
            <span class="time"><%= time_ago_in_words(ribbit.created_at) %></span>
            <p> <%= ribbit.content %> </p>
        </div>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem really lies in this line:

```
<%= form_tag relationship_path, method: :delete do %>
```

I suspect that the @relationship that you looked up in the show method should be supplied in the url helper:

```
<%= form_tag relationship_path(@relationship), method: :delete do %>
```

In current versions of Rails you can even shorten this to:

```
<%= form_tag @relationship, method: :delete do %>
```

Assuming that your model (Relationship) and has a corresponding controller (RelationshipsController) then Rails will correctly infer the url from your instance variable.

I'd second musicnerd47's suggestion that this should be a link instead of a form.

```
<%= link_to 'Unfollow', @relationship, method: :delete %>
```

That will be much easier to style.

Comment: Thanks this mostly fixed the problem but when this part 'redirect_to user_path params[:followed_id]' redirects it looks for an index method when I think I want it to be looking for the show method

Answer (score 0):

The params hash is anything that gets passed into the controller action. A good way of debugging it is to use `raise params.to_yaml` as the first line of the controller action. It lets you see what's being passed in. At the moment, it doesn't look like you're passing in the relationship that you should be destroying. Why not try using:

```
<%= form_tag relationship_path(@user.followed_relationships.where(follower: current_user)), method: :delete do %>
```

Alternatively, I definitely wouldn't use a whole form for your unfollow method. Why not just use a link? Instead of the form, you could try something like:

```
<%= link_to('Unfollow', relationship_path(@user.followed_relationships.where(follower: current_user)), method: :delete) %>
```